# Elasticsearch Capacity Planning Help Required

Tags: elasticsearch, capacity-planning

I am working on a elasticsearch cluster to have following requirements,

```
2000 TPS
10 kb payload
3 months retention period without summarising
1 year summarised data.
```

I have tried the same with 200tps instead 2000tps in a 3 node cluster with 16 core 64 GB computers. but it didn't even load a simple dashboard for a one month worth of data.
I searched internet, but couldn't find a proper document to create elasticsearch cluster for such large data set.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You might find this useful (and a little depressing!): https://thoughts.t37.net/designing-the-perfect-elasticsearch-cluster-the-almost-definitive-guide-e614eabc1a87

Comment: Thanks Adam, I will go though the article!